# Why is tensor product not giving me a block matrix?

Tags: tensors

I thought tensor product of $a = \begin{bmatrix} x \\y\end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ would give me $$a\otimes b =  \begin{bmatrix} x & 2x\\3x & 4x\\y & 2y \\ 3y & 4y\end{bmatrix}$$ But what mathematica gives me is,

[image: result]

Where am I going wrong? And what do I need to do in order to get the matrix that I want?

Comment: Try `KroneckerProduct` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where was I going wrong though? I mean is what I wanted not really the tensor product?

Comment: `TensorProduct` is used for *symbolic* manipulations. `KroneckerProduct` is for explicitly taking the tensor product of lists. Use the documentation to look up what these functions do!

Comment: I made an addendum to my answer that you will likely value if syntax is important to you.

Comment: The solution is found as one of *seventeen* separate examples in the documentation, and Mr. Wizard's (excellent) answer here has 4 upvotes.  Additionally, if the user doesn't already know what a Kronecker product is, the example won't really help because there is no visual output given; only equality is checked. I think this is sufficient reason to conclude that M.SE is better off for having this question, and that it shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **Properties & Relations** section of the [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html) documentation we find:

> The KroneckerProduct of matrices is equivalent to the flattening of
>   their TensorProduct to another matrix:
>
> ```
> mat1 = Array[a, {2, 3}];
> mat2 = Array[b, {4, 5}];
> KroneckerProduct[mat1, mat2] === ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[mat1, mat2]]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > True
> > ```
>
> The KroneckerProduct of any two arrays is also equivalent to a
>   flattening of their TensorProduct:
>
> ```
> arr1 = Array[a, {2, 3, 4, 5}];
> arr2 = Array[b, {4, 6}];
> KroneckerProduct[arr1, arr2] === ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[arr1, arr2], 3]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > True
> > ```

Solution: use [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html).

If you desire short notation you can make a simple assignment to one of the [unassigned operators](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) such as [`CircleTimes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleTimes.html):

```
CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct;

{{x}, {y}}⊗{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> ```
> {{x, 2 x}, {3 x, 4 x}, {y, 2 y}, {3 y, 4 y}}
> ```